# SVG: Динамическая погрузка / создание / добавление на страницу

Tags: javascript, svg

С помощью `JS` генерируется `svg` элемент и добавляется в `HTML`, но он не отображается. Есть в коде, но не рендерится. Если скопировать из дебаггера код и добавить в `html` вручную то все нормально. В чем проблема? Мне необходимо динамически подгружать различные `svg` объекты с которыми я должен взаимодействовать (ховер эффекты, считывание атрибутов при клике и т.д)

ВОПРОС как динамически погружать `svg` элементы? Не картинкой а именно объектом с кривыми `path`

Comment: Скорее всего браузер не умеет динамически подгружать svg, попробуйте загружать их через data-протокол. Укажите так же браузер. В ie с data-протоколом свои тонкости.

Comment: createElement/createElementNS

Answer (score 3):

Есть 2 способа создать `svg` из `js`

Создавать элементы через `document.createElementNS` используя пространство имен `svg` `http://www.w3.org/2000/svg` и добавляя их через `append`

```js
let ns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
let svg = document.createElementNS(ns, 'svg');
let circle = document.createElementNS(ns, 'circle');
circle.setAttribute('r', 50)
circle.setAttribute('cx', 60)
circle.setAttribute('cy', 60)
circle.setAttribute('fill', 'wheat')
svg.append(circle);
document.body.append(svg);
```

Добавлять через код `svg` через `innerHTML`, тогда `namespace` не нужен

```js
document.body.innerHTML += `<svg><circle r="50" cx="60" cy="60" fill="wheat"></circle></svg>`
```